# How does TestNG invoke a test method using multiple threads?

Tags: multithreading, testng

In the TestNG documentation, there is a section describing how to tell TestNG to invoke test methods using multiple threads:

> You can also specify that a @Test
>   method should be invoked from
>   different threads. You can use the
>   attribute threadPoolSize to achieve
>   this result:

```
@Test(threadPoolSize = 3, invocationCount = 10,  timeOut = 10000)
public void testServer() {
```

> **In this example, the function testServer will be invoked ten times
>   from three different threads.** (*emphasis mine*)

My question is whether the text above means that

1. the method will be run a total of
   10 times using 3 threads *or*
2. the method will be run a total of 30 times, with 3 threads running the method 10 times each.

My thought is that because the invocation count is associated with the method, 1 is the correct interpretation, but I would appreciate being corrected if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, 1 is the correct answer.

As a side note, writing a quick test case to verify this hypothesis would probably have been faster than writing up the question :-)

Comment: Yes, but I thought the answer might be useful to someone else. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use @Test(threadPoolSize = 3, invocationCount = 10,  timeOut = 10000) , which run asynchronous tests in multiple threads.

you may take a look: http://www.asjava.com/testng/testng-tutorial-time-test-with-annotation-timeout/